# Width in a fixed div when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been fighting with an issue for 2 days and it doesnt work...

I have a div with 980px width. Inside another div with 100% width, this other div when the window scrolls down its position goes fixed but gets the 100% width of the window.

How can I mantain the width? And what is more important, how can I do it responsive?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post JSFiddle or link?

Comment: code speaks more than words :) post your code or just add a fiddle :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jialberola/sKHY2/

Answer (score 0):

Option : Do you want to remove fixed position ? If Yes -

In HTML code, you put the future-fixed as id of div and in JS code, you keep

```
$("#future-fixed").css({'position' : 'fixed'});
```

make it commented.

I tried what I understand from your question.

Comment: Not exactly. When you do scrolling the red box gets the 100% width of the document, not the container width, I want to fix it when scrolling but with container width.
http://jsfiddle.net/jialberola/sKHY2/
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Mean you want to restrict the width of red container when you scroll ? Right ?

Comment: That is. I've tried to put the width in px, but always mantains the same pixels, include when resizing window.

I need to mantain the same visualization when scrolling that when not.

Answer (score 0):

You could just read out the width of the inner container as it gets the fixed position..

But you probably want to keep a container div at 100% with the position fixed so that you can center the content.

```
$('.outer').css({
    position: 'fixed',
    width: $('.inner').outerWidth()
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/sx24f/

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm going to try that path.